# How do I make the spaces between my links in my navbar wider?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the spaces between my links in my navbar wider? I am trying to make a website for my production company.

I want `Home` to be on far left, `Portfolio` to be on the left, `Contact` on the right, and `About` on far right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  Color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Sphinx Productions</h1>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
  <ul style="font-size:20px">
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`. [This page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is required reading regarding flex boxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Sphinx Productions</h1>
</div>

<ul>
     
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="news.asp">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>

  </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: I dont want to change the background color of sphinx to white i want it to stay black...but thanks i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS grid (flexbox is also an option), which will allow you to organize your links into 4 columns.

Create a div and set its display to grid:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 30% 30% 20%;

}
```

Change the grid-template-columns as needed to get the right spacing. You can adjust [column-gaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) and more, just look up the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout#css_properties).

Answer (score 0):

Just give padding in li in style.css

Like

```
li {
padding : 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  Color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
li:nth-child(3),
li:nth-child(4){
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Sphinx Productions</h1>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp" class = "links-right">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>

  </ul>
```

## What is `nth-child()`?

`nth-child()` is a pseudo-class css selector that selects a child and styles it using the css you put in.

***For example:***

```html
<body>
    <p>This is the first child of the body tag</p>
    <p>This is the second child</p>
    <p>This is the third child(selected)</p>
    <p>This is the fourth and last child</p>
</body>
```

```css
p:nth-child(3){
    -----
}
```

The `nth-child()` takes one argument and that is what child will be selected.

## What about `float`?

This is a property that will move elements to the position you input. It will stay structured with the rest of the elements.

***for example:***

```html
<p>first and second child will be selected</p>
<p>----me----</p>
<p> not me </p>
```

```css
p:nth-child(1),
p:nth-child(2){
    float: right;
}
```

They will go to the right, but it won't overlap or do anything crazy.

Comment: I want portfolio and about closer to the middle..Thanks anyway!